# C# compatible XML transformation in Java

Tags: java, xml, transformation

I have some trouble producing a compatible XML serialization for a DOM structure in Java, that is going to be processed in a C# application. The trouble comes from the fact, that the document contains a signature attribute on the top-level element.

The Java application calculates the hash and sets the value into a signature attribute which has been initialized with an empty string. The C# application reads the whole document, clears the signature attribute by placing an empty string into it again, serializes it in memory and calculates the hash (SHA256) over the complete data to verify the document's integrity. So far so good.

Unfortunately the results are not the same, although they should.

After some hours of investigation I realized, that the documents differ slightly when C# writes it into memory. C# seems to add a blank before the `\>` of empty elements, while Java does not. Even though this is a minor difference when viewing the docs in an editor, for calculation of a hash it is a problem. Since I only control the Java side, what options do I have to influence the serialization output of the Java XML transformer?

Currently I produce the output of the Java program with a transformer:

```
final Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();

transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Why do you have a custom signature algorithm? If you're using the XMLDSIG standard, libraries on both platforms should have worked out these problems.

Comment: You're right. But as I said, I only control the Java application. The C# part is a third party program, I cannot influence.

Comment: If the java signature-generation algorithm is taking into account things it shouldn't, like insignificant whitespace within tags, then (a) it's going to be very hard to reproduce the result after serialization and re-parsing, and (b) the signature is almost totally useless anyway. Why not just ignore it?

Comment: I understand your point. And if it were my app I would have used standards for key exchange and signatures. But unfortunately it isn't and I have to use it as is. Which means I have to patch this whitespace. I have chosen an ugly REGEX solution so far but I am not very proud of that...